# Word for an opening inside an island where water lies?

Tags: single-word-requests

What would be a word to name the opening of an island where a body of water (the ocean) enters into the land-mass?

I sketched an illustration of what I mean:

[image]

I know I have used a word to describe this before, but I have completely lost it.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Bay, lagoon, inlet?

Comment: @BoldBen thank you! Inlet is what I was looking for. If you put that as an answer with some definitions, I will give you the answer check.

Comment: Creek should be an option.

Comment: @RamPillai - A creek is a stream that flows from a source. What OP has pictured looks like it is filled with water from the main body (eg the ocean)  So not a creek.

Comment: An inlet is for any intrusion of a body of water and is not particular to islands. A lagoon is an inlet and interior bay of a coral atoll which is an island.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word [inlet](https://www.lexico.com/definition/inlet) is defined in this sense by Lexico as

> a small arm of the sea, a lake or a river

[bay](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bay) is defined by the same dictionary as

> a broad inlet of the sea where the land curves inward

So a bay is a broad inlet and an inlet is a narrow bay, exactly where an inlet becomes a bay is probably debatable.

Another term for an inlet can be [cove](https://www.lexico.com/definition/cove) which is

> A small sheltered bay.

but a cove usually has cliffs and curving arms which mean that the body of the cove is wider than it's mouth.

A [lagoon](https://www.lexico.com/definition/lagoon) is different in that it is

> A stretch of salt water separated from the sea by a low sandbank or coral reef.

From your comment it seems that you were looking for 'inlet'